# Vuetify v-dialog do not show in spite of value attribute equal to true

Tags: vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js, vue-reactivity

I am using vuex store state to show/hide Vuetify `v-dialog` in my NuxtJS app. Following are the code excerpt:

Vuex Store:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  dialogOpen: false
});

export const mutations = {
  setDialogToOpen(state) {
    state.dialogOpen = true;
  },
  setDialogToClosed(state) {
    state.dialogOpen = false;
  }
};
export const getters = {
  isDialogOpen: state => {
    return state.dialogOpen;
  }
};
```

Dialog Component:

```html
<v-dialog
  v-model="isDialogOpen"
  @input="setDialogToClosed"
  max-width="600px"
  class="pa-0 ma-0"
>
...
</v-dialog>
```

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters("store", ["isDialogOpen"])
},
methods: {
  ...mapMutations({
    setDialogToClosed: "store/setDialogToClosed"
  })
}
```

This all works fine but when I redirect from one page to another page like below it stops working.

```js
this.$router.push("/videos/" + id);
```

I hit browser refresh and it starts working again. Using the Chrome Vue dev tools, I can see the state is set correctly in the store as well as in the v-dialog value property as shown below

In Vuex store

[image]

In `v-dialog` component property

[image]

Yet the dialog is not visible. Any clue what is happening?

I am using `NuxtJS 2.10.2` and `@nuxtJS/Vuetify plugin 1.9.0`

Comment: Can you inspect your page and find the dialog ? maybe it has been rendered but the style it's different and not visible, maybe it has width : 0 by auto.

Comment: this occour because your push make reload your page. The state is created always when your page is loading. So when you reaload your page, your state is created again from the scratch . Another thing I think is, why you need save your v-dialog in state? Much better you create a component with a data dialogOpen.

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren even if it creates the state from scratch that should be fine because the starting state for `dialogOpen` is `false` only. The reason I am using vuex state to maintain the `v-dialog` is because it needs to be accessed from different parts of the application and using vuex store is easy to maintain than using something like an event bus. Also, it is weird that `value` attribute for `v-dialog` is true yet it does not show. But what is the fix?

Comment: ops "The reason I am using vuex state to maintain the v-dialog is because it needs to be accessed from different parts of the application and using vuex store is easy to maintain than using something like an event bus" 
if you use it inside a component, you don't need use vuex. Insted of you can use a simple data property. If you try you can see that you don't need vuex for this.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was due to `v-dialog` not being wrapped inside `v-app`

My code was structured like this

default layout

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-dialog
      v-model="isDialogOpen"
      @input="setDialogToClosed"
      max-width="600px"
      class="pa-0 ma-0"
    >
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

Below is the code for index page which replaces `nuxt` tag above at runtime.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      ...
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

So, in the final code `v-dialog` was not wrapped inside `v-app`. Moving `v-app` tag to `default` layout fixed it

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-dialog
      v-model="isDialogOpen"
      @input="setDialogToClosed"
      max-width="600px"
      class="pa-0 ma-0"
    >
    <nuxt />
  </v-app>
</template>
```